# How to disable Shipping Price in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I need to disable the shipping price option and want to add later into the order in the backend. In place of shipping rate, a message as "Shipping will be calculated and informed after placing the order".

How to do it?

We sell heavy materials, so there are lots of factor according to which we decide the shipping charge. There is no fixed rate chart.

Answer (score 0):

Once the order has been created in Magento it should not be changed.

What you need is essentially a quotation module, something like (https://www.cart2quote.com/magento2-quotation-module-editions.html).

You should also look at B2B feature of M2 Commerce or other platform like OroCommerce